# C++ : Pop_back a paired vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a paired vector like this

```
 vector <pair<int , string> > Names;
```

I put data in it this way:

```
cin>>taxi>>Ar_taxis>>Ar_mathiton;

        for(j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
        {
            cin>>Ar_Mitroou>>Onoma;
            Names.push_back(make_pair(Ar_Mitroou,Onoma));

        }
```

I sort it and then i print it:

```
  for(j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
        {
            cout<<Names[i].first<<" "<<Names[i].second<<endl;
           Names.pop_back();
        }
```

There's a problem with my pop_back() , it doesn't delete the set of pair. I don't know if there's another command to do it. Thanks.

[edit] the whole code

```
  cin>>Ar_taxeon;

for(i=0;i<Ar_taxeon;i++)
{
    cin>>taxi>>Ar_taxis>>Ar_mathiton;

        for(j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
        {
            cin>>Ar_Mitroou>>Onoma;
            Names.push_back(make_pair(Ar_Mitroou,Onoma));

        }

        sort(Names.begin(),Names.end());

        cout<<taxi<<Ar_taxis<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
        {
            cout<<Names[i].first<<" "<<Names[i].second<<endl;
           Names.pop_back();
        }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't remove it from the vector?  Did you check if the size changed?

Comment: The output is the same for all times. No, I haven't.

Comment: you are cycling over `j` and accessing `i`... that is already strange enough, show us the rest of the code when you check if it has been removed

Comment: The output is same since you are `i` as the index in `cout<<Names[i].first<<" "<<Names[i].second<<endl;` while the loop variable is `j`.

Comment: Why not just call `Names.clear()` after printing out the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following changes:

change name of variable `i` inside loop into `j`

and you can call Names.clear() after cout, instead of Names.popBack():

so your final code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
vector <pair<int , string> > Names;

int Ar_mathiton,Ar_Mitroou;
string Onoma;
cin>>Ar_mathiton;

for(int j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
{
    cin>>Ar_Mitroou>>Onoma;
    Names.push_back(make_pair(Ar_Mitroou,Onoma));

}
for(int j=0;j<Ar_mathiton;j++)
{
    cout<<Names[j].first<<" "<<Names[j].second<<endl;

}
Names.clear();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of problems with the example you posted.

The first one is that you are iterating over the list using `j`, but accessing `Names` with the index of `i`. However, even if you fixed that you would get a crash because you are iterating forward through the vector, but popping off the *back*, this means that you will eventually get an out-of-range error as the iterating index passes over the length of the list.

If you want to remove all items in one go, you should just call `Names.clear()`.

Additionally, it's bad form to be using C++ and not using the C++ way of iterating through lists.

Consider changing your second loop to the following:

```
for (auto& name : Names)
{
    cout << Names[j].first << " " << Names[j].second << endl;
}
```

Then finally, call this:

```
Names.clear();
```